# Application that can draw statistics from a Subversion repository?

Tags: svn

Is there any application that can give me a summary of what is going on in a SVN repository? I want to know things like:

- Number of lines of code
- Biggest contributor
- Most edited page
- etc

Is there any app that can provide any of this information, or is it something I would have to write myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like [StatSVN](http://statsvn.org/#So__what_is_StatSVN__Great_statistics_for_SVN_) could be what you're looking for:

> - Timeline for the lines of code
> - Lines of code for each developer
> - Activity by Clock time
> - Authors Activity
> - Author activity per Module
> - Author Most Recent Commits with links to ViewVc
> - Stats per directory
> - File count
> - Average file size
> - Largest files
> - Files with most revisions
> - Directory Sizes
> - Repository Tags Number of LOC per version.
> - Repository tree with file count and lines of code
> - LOC and Churn the evolution of LOC and the amount of change per day
> - Repo Map the dynamic hierarchical view of your repo for the last 30 days

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to use a project manager which integrates with SVN, such as [TRAC](http://trac.edgewall.org/). TRAC has [a lot of plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194361/what-are-some-recommended-plugins-for-trac) that should be capable of doing what you're asking. And if there's a statistic that isn't available via current plugins, you can easily write your own.

Otherwise, if your project is FOSS, you could just use [Github](http://github.com) (closed source apps can use Github as well, but you need a paid account), [Google Code](http://code.google.com), or [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net), which all provide project statistics out of the box.